# CoffeeScript - Show HTTP error status codes

Tags: http, coffeescript

So I've been trying to figure out how I can identify the error code associated with a http get error response in CoffeeScript.

Here is the function that I'm using

```
$scope.someRandomFunction = ->
    url  = $config.serverAddress + 'methodOnTheServer'
    url += '?someParameter=' + someParameter.ID
    $http.get(url)
    .success (tempFileName) ->
        link  = $config.serverAddress + 'anotherServerMethod'
        link += '?tempFileName=' + tempFileName
        link += '&desiredFilename=' + someParameter.Name
        $window.location.href = link
    .error (error) ->
        console.log "Unable to perform this action ", error
```

Here's a list of some sites and previous answers on this form that I had attempted:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-coffee4/

[Handling Http erorrs in coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906635/handling-http-erorrs-in-coffeescript)

[Coffeescript HTTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780669/coffeescript-http-client)

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, to get http status code, [add another parameter to the callback.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
$http.get(url)
  .success (tempFileName, status) ->
     console.log(status)
```

Comment: Ah, it went completely over my head to just read the AngularJS document... Thanks for that, that worked perfectly.